# jQuery Code Issue - Appending

Tags: jquery

This is my main code

```
<?php include"" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/ticket/loadComments.php"; ?>
<div id="commentsArea">
</div>
```

This is my jQuery below this:

```
channel.bind('TicketClient.SendComment', function(data) {
  $("#commentsArea").append("
             <div class='ticket-comment'>
             <span class='" + data.role + "-color'>" + data.name + "</span>
             <div class='formBreak'></div>
             <span class='text'>" + data.comment + "</span>
             </div><br>");
  alert(data.comment);
});
```

This won't append the code to the div and doesn't alert the data but without the appending code it seems to alert therefore, my error lies in that jQuery appending. Any help please.

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: Could you try with your souce code but not break new line in `append`.
Example: 
`$("#commentsArea").append("<div class='ticket-comment'><span class='" + data.role + "-color'>" + data.name + "</span><div class='formBreak'></div><span class='text'>" + data.comment + "</span</div><br>");`

Comment: you are binding to `TicketClient.SendComment` which if i am not wrong is an event ? when does it trigger?

Comment: The break lines in append is an issue for sure, see [@NguyenVQ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497998/jquery-code-issue-appending#comment-81951354) above

Comment: Where do you mean? the <br> and <div class='formBreak'>?

Comment: `append("` <- don't break here